# Treat strings as variables?

Tags: string-manipulation, linear-algebra, variable-definitions

I have a list of strings,

```
{"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"}
```

And a list of linear equations:

```
{"x1" + "x3" - "x4" == 0, "x1" + "x2" + "x3" == 0}
```

How can I use `Eliminate` to eliminate `"x1"` from these equations? It complains  that `"x1"` is not a valid variable. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I'd suggest you apply something like s_String:>v[s] to your list of equations before using Eliminate.

Comment: @Ymareth That works. My only complain is that it adds clutter.

Comment: You can use `Symbol[str]` to convert a string `str` into a symbol, and then work with the symbol in the usual way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the various `Solve` like functions don't show the same behavior concerning string-type variable names. Some do accept strings (e.g. `NDSolve` in version 9):

```
NDSolve[{"x"'["t"] == 0.1*"x"["t"], "x"[0] == 1}, "x", {"t", 0, 1}]
```

but others don't. For your case, `Eliminate` obviously doesn't, but you only need to convert those variables which you want to eliminate, like so:

```
Eliminate[{"x1" + "x3" - "x4" == 0, "x1" + "x2" + "x3" == 0} /. "x1" -> x1, x1]
```

you could even localize that variable, which won't prevent the variable to be generated in the `` Global` ``context but at least they won't be affected from any potential values of such a variable...

Answer (score 3):

```
var = {"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"};

eq = {"x1" + "x3" - "x4" == 0, "x1" + "x2" + "x3" == 0};

rules = Thread[var -> ToExpression[var]];

Eliminate[eq /. rules, x1]
```

> ```
> -x4 == x2
> ```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**
Try this

```
Eliminate[ToExpression[ToString[{"x1"+"x3"-"x4"==0,"x1"+"x2"+"x3"==0}]],{x1}]
```